# create-react-app loading slowly of my production server

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

I am try to search this question by google.But not helpful for me.
I hava a demo of create-react-app.
Run it in localhost(`npm start`), that work well when browser disable cache.for example:
[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfORT.png)

The step was run `npm run build` in localhost.then `scp -r build server:/home/deploy/app/`.run it by nginx.
Then open the browser to run,that initialization or refresh slowly when disable cache too. for example:
[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyWNw.png)

you could find load 500KB js file need 15seconds in server.

I guess that is a relationship with bandwidth. My server bandwidth was 1M/s.but i'm not sure.

ps: I'm sorry I forgot to declare the specific environment, but I did these steps.

Comment: I think my deployment was no problem.
1. `npm run build` on localhost.
2. `scp -r build server:/home/deploy/app/`
3.  [run it by nginx.](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app) 
I try to open it by browser, the js file load too slowly.
ps: why i don't `npm run build` in server. Because run it too slowly in server.

Comment: any cross-site problems or dead links? maybe a dead js links which points to your local systems or a missing favicon might slow down some things

Comment: I am allowed csrf and not have any error of favicon.

Comment: Hi guys,In the end, I can confim this problem was because of server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running this in production, I wouldn't suggest you running the web-application with `npm start` on the server.

A much better solution would be to run `npm run-script build` by which you'd get a response as such:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  48.12 KB  build/static/js/main.9fdf0e48.js
  288 B     build/static/css/main.cacbacc7.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  sudo npm install -g serve
  serve -s build
```

You could either do `serve -s build` or set up nginx or apache to serve the files (it's just html, css and js). You could also use Github Pages to host it.

Comment: thank for you reply. I'm run it by nginx.
[link](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app).

Comment: @xiaozhu If you could vote for the right answer, that would be lovely.

Comment: I want to do it, and two answer maybe right, but it is not help for me.I would wait for the lovest answer, .if not have anyone people answer, I would give you, please wait about for half a month.

Comment: @xiaozhu I don't think it's good to change the entirety of the question once it's been answered like that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the **build** step?

If yes, try `npm run build` or `yarn build`. It will output an optimized version of your app to `./build` directory. You can then host it on your server with `nginx` or other server setup.
More info here: [official docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build)

When you do `npm start` npm starts the **development version** of your app.
It includes some debug code, error checking and live refresh.

Comment: thank for you reply.
I'm run that by nginx.[like this](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app)